# Parallel.ForEach missing items

Tags: c#, .net, parallel.foreach

I've following code:

```
HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
RequestContext currentContext = RequestContextManager.CurrentContext;
ILifetimeScope currentSessionScope = PlatformContext.LifeTimeScope;

ConcurrentQueue<Exception> exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
ConcurrentBag<ParallelCalculateObj> forEachResult = new ConcurrentBag<ParallelCalculateObj>();
ConcurrentBag<ParallelCalculateObj> testForEachPassResult = new ConcurrentBag<ParallelCalculateObj>();

ParallelLoopResult loopResult = Parallel.ForEach(applications, () =>
{
    HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
    RequestContextManager.SetCustomCurrentContext(currentContext);
    PlatformContext.LifeTimeScope = currentSessionScope;
    return new ParallelCalculateObj();
}, (application, pls, localObj) =>
{
    try
    {
        // some code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exceptions.Enqueue(e);
    }
    testForEachPassResult.Add(localObj);
    return localObj;
}, forEachResult.Add);
```

where `applications.Count = 3`. After executing above code I got `forEachResult.Count = 2` and `testForEachPassResult.Count = 3`

Why forEachResult collection does not contain all of elements?
There is no exception and `ParallelLoopResult.IsCompleted = true`.

One thing that might be helpful in resolving my problem is that this three items was run under two threads:

1. Item01 -> Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId is 14
2. Item02 -> Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId is 10
3. Item03 -> Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId is 14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are using [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486(v=vs.110).aspx) in a wrong way.

You are using the overload which has a local state. This local state is unique for a partition/thread, but not every iteration has a unique local state.

Think of dividing the input list into *N* partitions. Then there are *N* local states. As the final step you have combine those *N* local states into your final value. In general *N* will be less than the number of items in the list and unless you use one of the more specific overloads the TPL will determine the way the list is partitioned.

Since you apparently want to fill some list with the result of every iteration your local state should be also a list which contains the result of every iteration of that particular partition. For the final action you combine all lists into one single list:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    applications,
    () => new List<ParallelCalculateObj>(),
    (application, pls, localObj) =>
    {
        // do something
        var obj = new ParallelCalculateObj { /* data of the iteration */ };
        localObj.Add(obj);
        return localObj;
    },
    localObj =>
    {
        foreach (var result in localObj)
        {
            forEachResult.Add(result);
        }
    });
```

Please note that if you do it like that then the order of values in `forEachResult` will not correspond to the order of items in `applications`. If you want that then you have to use the index of the `ParallelLoopState` class.

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you explain to me what is the purpose of using localFinally section? Can't I just add item to collection in body of the loop?

Comment: @MateuszPuwałowski The localFinally combines the result of each partition into one final value. Taking your example from the question: you have two partitions, the first containing Item01 and Item03 and the second Item02. The two local lists contain the results of processing Item01 and Item03, and the result of Item02. The localFinally step then merges those two lists into one containing all three results.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
  lock(testForEachPassResult){
     testForEachPassResult.Add(localObj);
   }
```

Most probably when adding an element, you are not having the latest state of the list. Remember the list could have another element added at the same time from another thread. So while it's changed, your adding the new item to an old version of testForEachPassResult.

If you lock the list, all the other threads will wait for the list to be unlocked.

Comment: That is why I'm using System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. It's thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways, two of which are mentioned already.

(1) Each loop creates a collection and adds its result to this task-result collection. When completed all task-results are combined. I would use this as default because if avoids lock contention.

(2) A common collection is created outside of all tasks. All tasks write to the collection but the write to this collection (adding items) must be synchronized with a lock because it is not atomic. I would use this if there are only a few 100 items to process but the processing time per item is one second or more. In this case the locking time is negligible.

(3) Create an array outside of all tasks and give each task a region to write the results to. Even though all tasks write to the same array the memory locations they write to are different. So there is no need for synchronization.

Example for (3)

```
// Source must be array or IList.
var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).ToArray();

// Partition the entire source array.
var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, source.Length);

double[] results = new double[source.Length];

// Loop over the partitions in parallel.
Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner, (range, loopState) =>
{
    // Loop over each range element without a delegate invocation.
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        results[i] = source[i] * Math.PI;
    }
});
```

Code from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl#configuring-static-range-partitioners-for-parallelforeach